# Collect all events in one year

Tags: php, sql

Hello can you help me I can't do this:

> - 2018
>
>   - event 1
>   - event 2

My current output:

> - 2018
>
>   - event 1
> - 2018
>
>   - event 2

I want do this without GROUP_CONCAT() without 2018 repeat

My code:

```
while($myrow=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$var = $myrow['event_date'];
    echo"
<p><b>" . date("Y", strtotime($var)) . "</b></p>
   <p> " . date("d.m.Y", strtotime($var)) ."
   "?>
    <a class="link" href="article.php?event_id=<?php echo $myrow['event_id'];?>"><?php echo $myrow['article_title'];?></a>
<b><a class="link" href="speaker.php?speaker_id=<?php echo $myrow['speaker_id'];?>"><?php
    echo"
    ".$myrow['speaker_degree']."
    ".$myrow['speaker_name']."
    ".$myrow['speaker_surname']."
    ".$myrow['speaker_patronymie']."
    </a></b></p>
";}
```

my query:

```
SELECT * FROM event_t\n" . "JOIN event_speaker_article_t ON event_t.event_id=event_speaker_article_t.event_id\n" . "JOIN article_t ON event_speaker_article_t.article_id=article_t.article_id \n" . "JOIN speaker_t ON event_speaker_article_t.speaker_id=speaker_t.speaker_id\n" . "ORDER by event_date
```

Comment: Why do you use mysqli_fetch_array and not wpdb? What does your SQL query look like?

Comment: @Krzysiek Dróżdż♦ my query is SELECT * FROM event_t\n" . "JOIN event_speaker_article_t ON event_t.event_id=event_speaker_article_t.event_id\n" . "JOIN article_t ON event_speaker_article_t.article_id=article_t.article_id \n" . "JOIN speaker_t ON event_speaker_article_t.speaker_id=speaker_t.speaker_id\n" . "ORDER by event_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, your events are already sorted by date, so all you have to do is to ignore header, previous event had the same year.

Let's also try to avoid all that spaghetti code, you've posted in question:

```
<?php
    $previous_year = false;
    while ( $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) :
        $event_datetime = strtotime($myrow['event_date']);
?>
    <?php if ( date('Y', $event_datetime) != $previous_year ) : ?>
    <p><b><?php echo date('Y', $event_datetime); ?></b></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <p><?php echo date('d.m.Y', $event_datetime); ?>
        <a class="link" href="article.php?event_id=<?php echo esc_attr($myrow['event_id']); ?>">
            <?php echo esc_html($myrow['article_title']); ?>
        </a>
        <b><a class="link" href="speaker.php?speaker_id=<?php echo esc_attr($myrow['speaker_id']); ?>">
            <?php echo esc_html($myrow['speaker_degree']); ?>
            <?php echo esc_html($myrow['speaker_name']); ?>
            <?php echo esc_html($myrow['speaker_surname']); ?>
            <?php echo esc_html($myrow['speaker_patronymie']); ?>
        </a></b>
    </p>
<?php
        $previous_year = date('Y', $event_datetime);
    endwhile;
?>
```

Another thing is... You shouldn't use `mysqli_*` functions in WP. There already is `WPDB` class to connect to DB and perform DB queries and you really should be using it instead.

Comment: ♦ your code display only first event_date and i don't use wpdb please can you fix your code that your code can display all data without repeating year thank you

Comment: @HermanFuturman If statement fixed. And I have no idea why don’t you use womb, because using mysqli is just wrong...